# How to trouble shoot timesynd service

Tags: systemd, time

How to trouble shoot the symptom where timesyncd service has been killed and cannot be found.

Timesyncd has been installed.

```
$ sudo apt -y install systemd-timesyncd
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
systemd-timesyncd is already the newest version (249.11-0ubuntu3.11pop0~1704473387~22.04~3ce38bf).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

However, the service cannot be found.

```
$ sudo systemctl status systemd-timesyncd
Unit systemd-timesyncd.service could not be found.
```

It looks it has been killed but not sure why.

```
$ sudo journalctl -fu systemd-timesyncd.service
Jul 31 09:31:40 pop-os systemd-timesyncd[602]: Initial synchronization to time server 185.125.190.56:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
-- Boot 67e30f40b57c4eadae6ed5a5b4df8c13 --
Jul 31 09:35:32 pop-os systemd[1]: Starting Network Time Synchronization...
Jul 31 09:35:33 pop-os systemd[1]: Started Network Time Synchronization.
Jul 31 09:36:03 pop-os systemd-timesyncd[660]: Initial synchronization to time server 185.125.190.56:123 (ntp.ubuntu.com).
Jul 31 09:40:53 pop-os systemd[1]: systemd-timesyncd.service: Current command vanished from the unit file, execution of the command list won't be resumed.
Jul 31 09:41:42 pop-os systemd[1]: systemd-timesyncd.service: Got notification message from PID 660, but reception is disabled.
Jul 31 09:42:42 pop-os systemd[1]: systemd-timesyncd.service: Watchdog timeout (limit 3min)!
Jul 31 09:42:42 pop-os systemd[1]: systemd-timesyncd.service: Killing process 660 (systemd-timesyn) with signal SIGABRT.
Jul 31 09:42:43 pop-os systemd[1]: systemd-timesyncd.service: Main process exited, code=dumped, status=6/ABRT
Jul 31 09:42:43 pop-os systemd[1]: systemd-timesyncd.service: Failed with result 'watchdog'.
```

timdatectl works.

```
$ timedatectl
               Local time: Wed 2024-01-17 15:00:42 AEDT
           Universal time: Wed 2024-01-17 04:00:42 UTC
                 RTC time: Wed 2024-01-17 04:00:42
                Time zone: Australia/Sydney (AEDT, +1100)
System clock synchronized: no
              NTP service: active
          RTC in local TZ: no
```

### Environment

```
$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Pop!_OS"
VERSION="22.04 LTS"
ID=pop
ID_LIKE="ubuntu debian"
PRETTY_NAME="Pop!_OS 22.04 LTS"
```

---

## Update

As suggested by [@paradin](https://serverfault.com/users/946161/paladin), the OS is using Chlony as the NTP client.

Comment: Can you check the sync with `timedatectl timesync-status`

Comment: Maybe your OS uses another NTP client. You PATH environment might be wrongly set. You may just create a symlink in /etc/systemd/system/ to (/usr)/lib/systemd/system/systemd-timesyncd.service and enable timesyncd. But you should definitiv check for any other NTP clients running and shut them down first.